# Passing mysqli to class for function use

Tags: php, oop, constructor, mysqli

Probably asked many times but I am hard-headed.

I have the following class to manage a MySQL db.

```
class blog {        
    function show ($mysqli) {
    // Code working on $mysqli here
    }
}
```

Since I will be using $mysqli in many functions inside of this class I read that I can create constructors in order to pass the $mysqli variable to the class and use it inside of each function so I can do something like:

```
$blog = new blog($mysqli);
$blog -> show();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Just use a field `$mysqli` in your class and initialize it in your constructor and use it via `$this->mysqli`:

```
class blog {  
    private $mysqli;

    function __construct(mysqli $mysqli) {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    function show () {
        // Code working on $this->mysqli here
    }
}
```

Comment: This means that I will have to write $this -> mysqli instead of $mysqli all the times, is that right? If so, is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Yes, in your class, you will have to use `$this->mysqli` to access the field. You cannot avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, thinking about it my last was a quite stupid question. I will have to write it only once. Thank you a lot.

Comment: You can, if you assign it to a privately scoped variable at the top of the function - but it is not suggested.

Comment: Another thing: what is the meaning of the arguments of __construct? I mean: (mysqli $mysqli)

Comment: It's expecting a variable of object type `mysqli`.

Comment: And if the argument is not an instance of `mysqli`, PHP will generate an error.

Comment: Last question and I promise I won't bore you again: private $mysqli. Since $mysqli is defined in another document (that I included in my .php file), with this row I am making the variable private? Because, if I delete it, it works anyway.

Comment: declaring it private means that if your class is used by another application, that application won't gain access to `$blog->mysqli`, and therefore the database.

Answer (score 1):

To store it in the class, would be something like:

```
class blog {
    private $mysqli;
    function __construct($dbi) {
        $this->mysqli = $dbi;
    }        
    function show () {
    $this->mysqli->query(); //example usage
    // Code working on $mysqli here
    }
}
```

And then in your code to use the class:

```
$blog = new blog($mysqli);
$blog->show();
```