# How to avoid multiple mysqli requests inside each class?

Tags: php, oop, methods, constructor, mysqli

I just know the basics of OOP. Actually I am using a MySQLi connection and I would like to avoid to call it each time inside Classes Methods. I would like to also avoid to include it as a parameter.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE);

class C1
{
    function F1()
    {
        // Using $mysqli->query();
    }

    function F2()
    {
        // Using $mysqli->query();
    }
}

class C2
{
    function F1()
    {
        // Using $mysqli->query();
    }
}
```

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803727/passing-mysqli-to-class-for-function-use) that barely helped me understand that using Constructors represents the direction to take but I don't understand concretely how to use them.

I tried something like that :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE);

class C1
{
    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct(mysqli $mysqli)
    {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public static function F1()
    {
        print_r($this->mysqli);
        // $mysqli = $this->mysqli;
    }
}

C1::F1();
```

But I got this error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\GitHub\PhpRestDoc\test.php on line 38

Comment: You need to instantiate `C1`, i.e. create an instance of it (`$C1 = new C1($mysqli); $C1->F1();`). Then `$this` will become available, and the constructor will be run. Have a look at the PHP manual for objects - that should give you a good introduction.

Comment: you must create instance from class C1  => $c1 = new C1($mysqli) ; $c1->F1();

Comment: You cannot use `$this` within a static method. Lose the `static` keyword on your `F1` method

Comment: Thank you very much ! Indeed, by instancing it and taking off the "static", it does work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use static methods, your code will look something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE);

class C1
{
private static $mysqli;

public static function setConnection($db) 
{
    self::$mysqli = $db;
}

public static function F1()
{
    print_r(self::$mysqli);
    // $mysqli = self::$mysqli;
}
}

C1::setConnection($mysqli);

C1::F1();
```

You can also create instance of it:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE);

class C1
{
private $mysqli;

public function __construct($mysqli)
{
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
}

public function F1()
{
    print_r($this->mysqli);
    // $mysqli = $this->mysqli;
}
}

$model = new C1($mysqli);
$model -> F1();
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Deepsy ! (I just took off the "static" for the second one)